# How can I run Open Liberty without enabling the javaagent: wlp/bin/tools/ws-javaagent.jar?

Tags: javaagents, open-liberty

While using OpenLiberty docker image I found that by default `ws-javaagent.jar` enabled on server. Is their any way skip this ?

Comment: Sarang, I'm pretty sure you're only asking to remove the agent from the JVM execution...not to rebuild the image minus the JAR, and this explains my answer below.   I'm going to edit the question to clarify this if you don't object.

Comment: Yes Scott. Is it possible to run `monitor-1.0` server feature without ws-javaagent.jar ?

Comment: I think the `monitor-1.0` feature does require this agent.. the WebSphere Liberty doc:  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSD28V_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.core.doc/ae/twlp_monitor10.html  seems to say it is needed, and this function is essentially the same in Open Liberty.

Comment: Right. Thanks a lot @ScottKurz for more details. It worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable simply by setting environment variable:
`WLP_SKIP_BOOTSTRAP_AGENT=true`

As noted in the Open Liberty [doc](https://openliberty.io/docs/latest/reference/command/server-start.html#_server_process_properties) this will prevent you from using certain trace and monitoring capabilities.